# Responsive multiple images to create single image using css

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a banner using 3 images as shown in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OroMKB)
The view is all ok if it is over 1200px but when screen size goes down, it gets overlapping.

```css
.yourlimit img:first-child{
    position: absolute;
    left: -8%;
    bottom: 0;
}

.yourlimit img:last-child{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40%;
    right: -8%;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container px-md-0 my-5 mx-auto position-relative text-center yourlimit">
            <img class="" src="https://i.ibb.co/GWFDsFk/limit-left-border.png" alt="">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/t2388tK/limit-img.png" alt="">
            <img class="" src="https://i.ibb.co/XjHJ1dZ/limit-right-border.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not add media queries? Seems like the best option.

Comment: What's the desired output look like for all sizes? Since you've got your first/last absolute positioned with percentages it's assumed you know `img-fluid` class won't apply since it's omitted from those 2 elements. So like jleggio pointed out, media queries are probably the best bet unless the way it's presented is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest making the main, center image (https://i.ibb.co/t2388tK/limit-img.png) not have the white lines on either end that are already covering up some of the text - that will be impossible to line up across browsers and screen sizes.

Next, I achieved the desired effect by adjusting your CSS. I removed the `bottom` rules because that was preventing the images align at the top, which makes it simpler to adjust IMO. I also set the first image to `left: 0;` and the last image to `right: 0`.

From there, your have the following rules to adjust until you get what you want are the width of each image:

1. width of each image (in percentages for responsive layout)
2. absolute positioning if you really need to, but I don't think it's necessary.

Here's my new CSS to plug into your Codepen. Note that I put red borders around the images just to get a sense of where they are - obviously remove these once you're done.

```
    img {
        border: solid red 1px;
    }
    .yourlimit img:first-child{
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        width: 20%;
    }

    .yourlimit .img-fluid {
      width: 80%;
    }

    .yourlimit img:last-child{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        width: 20%;
    }
```

Comment: I just noticed that the right image is way down from where it should be placed. Infact the blue bar should be aligned to the shadow of the center image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to target the two images so that the size is reduced on smaller screens.

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .yourlimit img:last-child{
      width: 50%;
  }

  .yourlimit img:first-child{
      width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Note that you will have to adjust the width in order to determine what will work best for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

As the screen gets smaller in width the container shrinks as well. So your left and right images are +-8% of the scrunched up container. The easiest option is to give the container the width of the center image:

```
.container {
  width: 1140px;
}
```